Remove lines from csv file
I have a csv file that contains, file share path, username and permissions, like this:
"FolderName";"ADGroupOrUser";"Permissions"
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user.user;  Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user1.user1;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user2.user2;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2\1 - folder3;   user.user;  Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2\1 - folder3;   user1.user1;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2\1 - folder3;   user2.user2;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2\1 - folder3\folder4;   user.user;  Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2\1 - folder3\folder4;   user1.user1;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2\1 - folder3\folder4;   user2.user2;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2\2 - folder1;   user.user;  Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2\2 - folder1;   user1.user1;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2\2 - folder1;   user2.user2;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\2 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user.user;  Modify, Synchronize
\\path\2 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user1.user1;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\2 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user2.user2;    Modify, Synchronize
...

As you can see from the first 3 lines, the folder path is the same but the users are different.
The next 6 lines of the network path have another folder, but the users and permissions are the same because it's inherited from the parent.
The idea is to remove these 6 lines from the file, because as the permissions are inherited everything that follows will have the same user and the same permissions
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2\1 - folder3
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2\1 - folder3\folder4

In this case, the final result should be:
"FolderName";"ADGroupOrUser";"Permissions"
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user.user;  Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user1.user1;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user2.user2;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\2 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user.user;  Modify, Synchronize
\\path\2 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user1.user1;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\2 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user2.user2;    Modify, Synchronize

I'm using bash (MacOS) to process the file
something like this
grep -v "\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2*"

this path has more folders
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2*

then delete

What have you tried so far?

And what is the field separator here? Should we assume ;? All of your lines have more content than path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2, do you mean that you want to remove lines if the first field, as defined by the ; contains more than 2 \ ? And what operating system are you using? You had added the Linux tag, does that mean you're using Linux?

It is unclear what you mean by "more content".

yes the field separator is ;.

When creating sample input/output it's best to use realistic values for your data, don't just repeat path and folder everywhere that a path or a folder name should appear and similarly for user, etc. otherwise you're likely to get solutions that work for your posted example but fail for your real data. For example, I doubt if my answer is what you really want but it produces the expected output from your sample input so maybe it is, idk, without more realistic sample input/output we're just guessing at your needs.

In Unix a folder (directpry) name can contain ; so please [edit] your question to state/show if ;s can appear in any of the path or folder names in your file.

$ { head -n 1; grep -E '^.{32};'; } < file
"FolderName";"ADGroupOrUser";"Permissions"
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user.user;  Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user1.user1;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user2.user2;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\2 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user.user;  Modify, Synchronize
\\path\2 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user1.user1;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\2 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user2.user2;    Modify, Synchronize

If that's not actually what you need then edit your question to provide better requirements.

Does that just eliminate the lines over thirty characters in length?

@Conrado it eliminates all lines that are not at least 31 characters long with the 31st character being ';', which I believe matches what they're asking in the "path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2*" line and the output.

Ed, your code will remove all the lines from the example.

@RomeoNinov the OP recently changed their sample input, output by adding 2 more chars to the front and a header line so I just updated my answer to match.

Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)
~$ raku -ne '.put unless /^ \\\\ path \\ [[ <digit>+ " - "]? folder \s? <digit>* ]**3..* \% "\\" /;'  file

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family. It features high level support for Unicode as well as a powerful regex engine.
Above, a one-liner is invoked with the -ne non-autoprinting linewise execution flags. The .put statement in short for $_.put meaning to output the topic (i.e. line) unless the regex matches.
Regex interpretation:  Each line is assumed to ^ start with \\path\. To decipher the remainder of the regex, understand that [column]**X % "sep" is a new idiom in Raku, a.k.a. the "modified-quantifier" idiom. This idiom basically defines columns having a common separator (in this case, the \ backslash character). You can select for a certain X number/range of columns. To get the OP's desired output, 3..* three-or-more \ backslash-separated columns after start-of-line \\path\ are disallowed, hence restricting the output to two-or-less \ backslash-separated columns after path\, which is apparently what the OP desires.
Sample Input:
"FolderName";"ADGroupOrUser";"Permissions"
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user.user;  Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user1.user1;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user2.user2;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2\1 - folder3;   user.user;  Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2\1 - folder3;   user1.user1;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2\1 - folder3;   user2.user2;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2\1 - folder3\folder4;   user.user;  Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2\1 - folder3\folder4;   user1.user1;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2\1 - folder3\folder4;   user2.user2;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2\2 - folder1;   user.user;  Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2\2 - folder1;   user1.user1;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2\2 - folder1;   user2.user2;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\2 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user.user;  Modify, Synchronize
\\path\2 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user1.user1;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\2 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user2.user2;    Modify, Synchronize

Sample Output:
"FolderName";"ADGroupOrUser";"Permissions"
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user.user;  Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user1.user1;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\1 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user2.user2;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\2 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user.user;  Modify, Synchronize
\\path\2 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user1.user1;    Modify, Synchronize
\\path\2 - folder 01\1 - folder2;   user2.user2;    Modify, Synchronize

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Modified_quantifier:_%,_%%
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org

In awk you can use command like:
awk -F\\ 'NF<4{ print}' input_file

This will use \ as delimiter and count the number of field. And print if fields are less than 4
P.S. As you edit the post and change the examples the command change to :
awk -F\\ 'NF<6{ print}' input_file


the file has much more than the example, I think it has to be by pattern because there are certainly paths with more than 4 that will be valid.

@Hugo, w/o full example we can't provide solution. Add in example all the possible variations of the source.

Thank you all for your help. I've found a solution that works for me:
grep -v "path\\\\1.-.folder.01\\\\1.-.folder2\\\\"


Use single quotes around all strings and scripts by default, not double quotes. If you do that you'll need half as many backslashes. Your script will fail given various contents of your input file regardless of that though.

thanks you i'll

if this work is to be done on a one-off, I would import the csv into MS Excel or LibreOffice (import file separated by ';' and use a trivial filter to delete those row that count the '' char in the path: if it's > 1
i.e. add a column with formula -> LEN(cell file share path)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(file share path,"",""))>1
If, on the other hand, you intend to build a process, I would use a SQL db and, after importing the file with the fields separated by ';', I would set a query/store Procedure  with DELETE command.
i.e. DELETE * FROM <imported_table> WHERE LEN() - LEN(REPLACE(, "", "")) >1
The syntax is to be refined/adapted to the structure of the table you will create

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
